# Managing authorization based on employee - manager relations (nextjs14 app router, supabase auth, postgresql, typescript)

Tags: postgresql, authentication, next.js, authorization, supabase

I'm looking for some advise on an authorization strategy. I've implemented supabase authentication. My Application manages employee activities (managing sensitive client data) and manager supervision on those activities.

- Employees are part of one or more teams and each team can have one or multiple managers.
- Employees need to be able to access their own pages (with employeeAccess role)
- Managers need to be able to access the employee pages of all employees that are part of their team (with managerAccess role).
- Because of the sensitivity of data handled it is absolutely crucial that no one can ever get accidental access to another employees pages if they are not their manager!
- The individual employee pages have a multitude of sub pages where both the manager and employee will be able to execute a variety of CRUD operations based on their type of access

Now my question is how to manage this properly taking into consideration performance without compromising on security. I now made the following setup where I have the following functions:

- getCurrentUser ( Checks if user is logged in await supabase.auth.getUser(); and returns the user id, otherwise redirects to login
- getManagerTeams (accepts the userId of the current user and checks which teams the current user has access to as a manager in the database and returns an array of teamIds
- getEmployeeTeams (accepts the userId based on the slug in the url, checks which teams this user is part of in the database and returns an array of teamIds
- CheckUserAccess (calls the other three functions and returns the userAccess level for that employee page:

```
import getCurrentUser from "./getCurrentUser";
import getManagerTeams from "./getManagerTeams";
import getEmployeeTeams from "./getEmployeeTeams";

export default async function checkUserAccess(
  employeeProfileId: string
  // accepts the employeeId from the slug
) {
  const currentUser = await getCurrentUser();
  const managerTeams = await getManagerTeams(currentUser);
  const employeeTeams = await getEmployeeTeams(employeeProfileId);

  if (currentUser === employeeProfileId) {
    return "employeeAccess";
  } else if (
    employeeTeams.some((employeeTeam) => managerTeams.includes(employeeTeam))
  ) {
    return "managerAccess";
  } else {
    return "noAccess";
  }
}
```

In the current setup I would have to call this on every single employee page and sub page load, and am wondering if there are issues with this and if there is not a more performant way of doing this without compromising on security? Can anyone point me in the direction of best practices on how to manage this type of authorization structure? Thanks in advance!

I'm already using my middleware.ts on protected routes to update the JWT cookie based on Supabase SSR auth documentation (Since Server Components can't write cookies, you need middleware to refresh expired Auth tokens and store them.), and as far as I can tell next allows only one middleware.ts

Comment: There's a couple of approaches to this. You might want to check out https://usebasejump.com/ and https://github.com/cfeenstra67/sqlauthz as options to evaluate.